# How to store 1.5 GB CSV files?

Tags: open-source, python, database, csv, distributed

I am searching a solution to store files of 1.5 GB. There is a decade of file per day.

I am searching a solution to store those files.
I have already done some searches on HDFS and MongoDB. However, I do not manage to determine if they are good tools for my problem. And moreover, I can not find if I am missing another possible/better tool.

I have the following requirements:

- New documents available in few seconds (maximum)
- Solution which can be distributed
- If the solution as a plugin in Logstash it is a plus
- Open source
- I need redundancy for the stored files
- I need to pull the files from python
- Shortest time possible to retrieve the files
- I do not want from a cloud solution (e.g.: Amazon S3)

Comment: Have you considered mariadb?  You can import CSV files directly into a database.  Every programming language has database support so python access is a non-issue.  You can have 2 or more mariadb installations. https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-mariadb-master-and-slave-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I didn't considered mariaDB I will take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: besides creating indexes, fast storage will decrease the access time.  A M.2 SSD can get 2500mb/s read and 1500mb/s write easy.  Even faster ones exist up to 3500mb/s read and writes speeds approx 2500.(maybe more)